# jquery flot zoom selection is not working for to charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am new in jQuery flot, I have two charts I want to connect the two for zoom and selection functionality,

Code:

```
      // now connect the two

  $("#time_chart").bind("plotselected", function(event, ranges) {

    // clamp the zooming to prevent eternal zoom

    if (ranges.xaxis.to - ranges.xaxis.from < 0.00001) {
      ranges.xaxis.to = ranges.xaxis.from + 0.00001;
    }

    if (ranges.yaxis.to - ranges.yaxis.from < 0.00001) {
      ranges.yaxis.to = ranges.yaxis.from + 0.00001;
    }

    // do the zooming

    plot = $.plot("#time_chart", time_series,
      $.extend(true, {}, options, {
        xaxis: {
          min: ranges.xaxis.from,
          max: ranges.xaxis.to
        },
        yaxis: {
          min: ranges.yaxis.from,
          max: ranges.yaxis.to
        }
      })
    );

    // don't fire event on the overview to prevent eternal loop

    time_overview.setSelection(ranges, true);
  });

  $("#time_overview").bind("plotselected", function(event, ranges) {
    plot.setSelection(ranges);
  });
```

Please see the demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/w47agnq2/

My chart displays the data correctly but I feel for connecting both two I am doing some mistake.

```
$.plot("#time_chart", time_series,
          $.extend(true, {}, options, {
```

while passing `time_series`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some corrections it works, see the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w47agnq2/1/).

**Changes:**

Adding `http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.selection.js` to External Resources.

```
$.plot($("#time_chart"), [time_series], time_options);
var plot = $.plot($("#time_chart"), [time_series], time_options);

plot = $.plot("#time_chart", time_series,
plot = $.plot("#time_chart", [time_series],

$.extend(true, {}, options, {
$.extend(true, {}, time_options, {
```

Comment: Thanks.. for that.. I find the solution already.. I was not passing my time_series properly while connecting..

Comment: I was searching for mouse zoom and drag functionality... Can you please provide any link ??

Comment: See the [Navigation / Panning and zooming](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/navigate/index.html) example from the Flot page.